# How to put diffent color in some cells in this matrix using Tikz?

Tags: color, tikz-styles, nodes, tikz-matrix, fill

I got this matrix bellow :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \matrix [nodes={fill=red!20,minimum size=15mm}]
  
{

    \node {27}; & \node{12}; & \node {12}; & \node {16}; & \node{24}; & \node {31}; & \node {41}; & \node{13};\\
    \node {14}; & \node{5}; & \node {37}; &\node {9}; & \node{36}; & \node {25}; & \node {1}; & \node{34};\\
    \node {34}; & \node{34}; & \node {20}; &\node {9}; & \node{19}; & \node {19}; & \node {3}; & \node{34};\\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I wannt to choose some cells and color them with green

Comment: what about `\node[fill=green]{};`?

Comment: Or `row 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}` and `row 2 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=red}}` to give just some ideas.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!